# Explanation of what is actually happening in ES6 Rest paramter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Please explain the following example.I am not able to understand what is actually happening here.Thank you in advance

```
 function f (x, y, ...a) {
        return (x + y) * a.length
    }
    f(1, 2, "hello", true, 7) === 9
```

Comment: why don't just console.log(a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rest takes the 'rest' of the arguments and puts in them in an array which is assigned to `a`.

Your return statement turns into `(1+2) * 3`, which equals 9.

A simpler example:

```
[x, y, ...a] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

console.log(x)
// 1
console.log(y)
// 2
console.log(a)
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think of arguments being passed as a simple array, then the following

```
function f(a,b,...c){...}
```

Can be converted to:

```
function f(args){
  var a = args[0],
      b = args[1],
      c = args.slice(2);
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //function is getting defined here.
  function f (x, y, ...a) {
        return (x + y) * a.length
    }

   //function is getting called here.
  f(1, 2, "hello", true, 7) === 9
```

When your function f is called, Inside the function f, your code takes `x as 1, y as 2`, and a as an array containing `["hello", true, 7]`. So, `array a has length 3`.

Your result of the function is `(1 + 2) * 3`, which is `9`.

So, your comparison of function result to 9, is true.